# Pasting .bin image files into excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, bin

I've been trying to write a script to fetch images and paste them all together into one file. For this I use ZipFile from zipfile to extract .bin image files from a collection of .xlsx files and I planned to use openpyxl to paste them all into one new .xlsx file.

When I run this, I end up getting a KeyError: '.wmf'.

I tried converting the image type to .png (or other raster image types). This did fix the issue, but the .bin image files seem to act a bit like a vector type of image and I would like to keep this attribute.

I would love to know how to fix this, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os
import xlsxwriter as xw

"Function to find location of images"
imgformats = ('bin')
def is_image(filename):
    return any(filename.endswith(ext) for ext in imgformats)

"Create folder"
folders = ['imgsave']
for folder in folders:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)

"Group the files"
path = Path(".")
try:
    files = path.glob('*.xlsx')
except PermissionError as e:
    print(f'Permission Error: {str(e)}')
    sys.exit()

"Set variables"
file_count = 0
overall_size = 0
data = []

"Loop over files and extract the images"
if not os.path.exists('xl'):
    for file in files:
        with ZipFile(file) as working_zip:
            image_list = [name for name in working_zip.namelist() if is_image(name)]
            for img in image_list:
                overall_size = overall_size + working_zip.getinfo(img).file_size
            file_count = len(image_list)
            working_zip.extractall("", image_list)
            for img in image_list:
                os.rename(img, f'xl/media/{file}.bin')
            data.append(file_count)
            data.append(overall_size)


"Create list of pasting locations for in excel"
cellcycletemp = ['A', 'H', 'O', 'V', 'AC']
rows = 4
cellcycle = [cellcycletemp[n%rows] + str(n//rows+1+12*(n//rows)+1) for n in range(120)]

"Create excel file and paste .bin images into it"
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

imagelist = [img for img in os.listdir('xl/media/.') if '.bin' in img]
for n, file in enumerate(imagelist):
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('xl/media/' + file)
    img.anchor = cellcycle[n]
    ws.add_image(img)
    wb.save('imgsave/combined images.xlsx')
```

This is the error I end up getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<path>\test_zipandpaste.py", line 67, in <module>
    wb.save('imgsave/combined images.xlsx')
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 94, in write_data
    self.manifest._write(archive, self.workbook)
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py", line 181, in _write
    self._register_mimetypes(filenames=archive.namelist())
  File "C:\<path>\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py", line 193, in _register_mimetypes
    mime = mimetypes.types_map[True][ext]
KeyError: '.wmf'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

edit: found a mistake in the code I posted originally and fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to do it without openpyxl. Python has a build-in library xlsxwriter which can handle .wmf files and allows it to paste the .bin files as well.

```
import xlsxwriter as xw

wb = xw.Workbook('imgsave/combined images.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

imagelist = [img for img in os.listdir('xl/media/.') if '.bin' in img]
for n, file in enumerate(imagelist):
    ws.insert_image(cellcycle[n], f'xl/media/{file}')
wb.close()
```

Comment: It's not correct to say that XLSXWriter can "handle" WMF (Windows Meta Files): image handling, such as getting the size, etc. depends on other libraries (in Python generally Pillow) and on the operating system EMF/WMF is generally limited to Windows. There isn't a "bin" graphics format, with the extension generally used for binary code.

Comment: Not really related to the question but XlsWriter does actually parse dimensions and DPI from image files itself, including WMF.

Comment: I was also surprised to find that the images were with the .bin extension. I had never seen this before. The image viewer from Windows was also unable to open and view it. With Pillow I was able to open it, but only the resolution of the image was correct, for the rest all the pixels were white.